# Why doesn't this bash script execute on Ubuntu, but does on an online environment?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I can't figure out why this does not work properly on Ubuntu. It works great when I execute the script on [CompileOnline](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_bash_online.php); but when I run it on a local server it does not give me the main menu and skips into reading the list of commands from the top.

The script is supposed to be a menu system. Based upon which selection the user inputs is what action happens. There are also comments so you can see what each section of code does.

```
    #!/bin/su

    # Ititialization

    function installsamba {
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
      sudo apt-get -y install git build-essential libacl1-dev libattr1-dev libblkid-dev libgnutls-dev libreadline-dev python-dev python-dnspython gdb pkg-config libpopt-dev libldap2-dev dnsutils libbsd-dev attr krb5-user docbook-xsl libcups2-dev acl
      git clone git://git.samba.org/samba.git samba-master
      cd samba-master
      ./configure
      sudo make
      sudo make install
      sudo rm -f -R samba-master
      sed -i "5i PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/samba/bin" ~/.bashrc
      sed -i "5i PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/samba/sbin" ~/.bashrc
      sudo sed -i "5i PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/samba/bin" /root/.bashrc
      sudo sed -i "5i PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/samba/sbin" /root/.bashrc
      mainmenu
      }

    # This installs all of the necessary components for building samba then downloads samba from git.
    # After that it then compiles and installs samba and returns to the main menu.

    function installvsftpd {
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
      sudo apt-get -y install vsftpd
      mainmenu
      }

    # This installs VSFTPd and return to the main menu.


    function installwebmin {
      wget http://www.webmin.com/download/deb/webmin-current.deb
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
      sudo dpkg -i webmin-current.deb
      sudo apt-get -y install -f
      rm webmin-current.deb
      mainmenu
      }

    # This installs the current version of WebMin and then returns to the main menu.

    function updatesystem {
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
      echo "Update Complete!"
      echo "It may be wise to restart your computer..."
      read -N 1
      clear
      mainmenu
      }

    # This install the latest updates for the system and then returns to the main menu.


    function configuresambaforactivedirectory {
      sudo sed -i.original -r '/[ \t]\/[ \t]/{s/(ext4[\t ]*)([^\t ]*)/\1\2,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1/}' /etc/fstab
      mount -a
      sudo /usr/local/samba/bin/samba-tool domain provision
      sudo mv /etc/krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf.bak
      sudo cp /usr/local/samba/private/krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf
      sudo sed -i "13i sudo /usr/local/samba/sbin/samba" /etc/rc.local
      sudo /usr/local/samba/sbin/samba
      domaincontrolleryorn
      }

    # This function runs all of the necessary actions to make samba a domain controller.


    function domaincontrolleryorn {
      echo "did you set this instalation as a primary domain controller?"
      echo ""
      echo "If you select yes then it will upgrade the forrest and domain to"
      echo "Server 2008 R2 levels. This may break compatibility with earlier"
      echo "versions of Windows Server. You can alwayse manually change the levels"
      echo "if you wish... Press wisely!"
      echo ""
      echo "Y or N:"
      read -N 1 -p "Y or N:" domaincontrolleryesorno
      if [ $domaincontrolleryesorno = "Y" ]; then
       upgradeforrestanddomain
       elif [ "$$domaincontrolleryesorno" = "N" ]; then
                clear
                echo "Samba configuration complete!"
                echo "Press any key to continue..."
                read -N 1
                mainmenu
        elif [ "$$domaincontrolleryesorno" = "n" ]; then
                clear
                echo "Samba configuration complete!"
                echo "Press any key to continue..."
                read -N 1
                mainmenu
        elif [ "$$domaincontrolleryesorno" = "y" ]; then
                upgradeforrestanddomain
        else
          echo "Please press either Y or N!!!"
          echo ""
          echo "Press any key to continue..."
          read -N 1
          clear
          domaincontrolleryorn
        fi
      }

# This asks the user if he or she would like to upgrade the domain and forrest level.
# If yes then it roputs the user to the code below. If not then the user is taken to the main menu.

    function upgradeforrestanddomain  {
      sudo /usr/local/samba/bin/samba-tool domain level raise --domain-level=2008_R2
      sudo /usr/local/samba/bin/samba-tool domain level raise --forest-level=2008_R2
      sudo /usr/local/samba/bin/samba-tool domain passwordsettings set --complexity=off
      echo "Domain Controller setup has completed!"
      echo ""
      echo "Press any key to return to the main menu..."
      read -N 1
      clear
      mainmenu
      }


    # This function upgrade the Domain and Forrest level to (Server) 2008_R2.
    # Acceptable levels are 2008 and 2008 R2. The default is 2003.


    function quitprogram {
      clear
      echo "Sorry to see you go... :("
      exit
      }

    # This is a simple good by program closer.
    # Oh, did I mention that it stops the program?


    function mainmenu {
      echo "Press 1 to update your system"
      echo "Press 2 to install samba"
      echo "Press 3 to install vsFTPd"
      echo "Press 4 to install the current version of Webmin"
      echo "Press 5 to configure samba for Active Directory"
      echo "Press x to exit the script"
      read -N 1 -p "Input Selection:" mainmenuinput
      if [ "$mainmenuinput" = "1" ]; then
                updatesystem
            elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "2" ]; then
                installsamba
            elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "3" ]; then
                installvsftpd
            elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "4" ]; then
                installwebmin
            elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "5" ]; then
                configuresambaforactivedirectory
            elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "x" ];then
                quitprogram
            elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "X" ];then
                quitprogram
            else
                echo "You have entered an invallid selection!"
                echo "Please try again!"
                echo ""
                echo "Press any key to continue..."
                read -N 1
                clear
                mainmenu
            fi
    }

    mainmenu

    # This executes the main menu function.
    # Let the fun begin!!!! WOOT WOOT!!!!
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: BTW you should add comments before code. i.e first comment then function.

Comment: Did you really intend the shebang to be `#!/bin/su`? Shell scripts would normally use either `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` (you'd need bash in this case because of the function defs, I think). By default, the root account is not even enabled on Ubuntu so I'm not even sure `/bin/su` will be able to spawn a shell interpreter.

Comment: I will look into it. The reason I used the `/bin/su` is because it was in the Ubuntu examples.

Comment: OMG!!! I just looked at the Ubuntu samples and the were `sh`!!! I must have misread them XD.

Comment: @AdityaPatil Why is your reason for doing this? I do this so the person can see the code then they can know what it does.

Comment: @elliotlabs Writing comment first is generally accepted standard.It is the way used in about everything I have seen, which includes libraries, header files.FOSS softwares etc.

Comment: @AdityaPatil Ok I will rewrite the comments to be ahead of the code. Thanks for the info!

Comment: If you solved the problem, please, post an answer and accept it so it will be not anymore in the list of unanswered/unsolved question.

Comment: ok I will get the script's code together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was creating the functions incorrectly for Ubuntu.
I also changed the shebang just to make sure that the system would interpret it correctly but I do not think that it made much of a difference :-P
Here is the code that works:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Ititialization

installsamba () {
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
  sudo apt-get -y install git build-essential libacl1-dev libattr1-dev libblkid-dev libgnutls-dev libreadline-dev python-dev python-dnspython gdb pkg-config libpopt-dev libldap2-dev dnsutils libbsd-dev attr krb5-user docbook-xsl libcups2-dev acl
  git clone git://git.samba.org/samba.git samba-master
  cd samba-master
  ./configure
  sudo make
  sudo make install
  sudo rm -f -R samba-master
  sed -i "5i PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/samba/bin" ~/.bashrc
  sed -i "5i PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/samba/sbin" ~/.bashrc
  sudo sed -i "5i PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/samba/bin" /root/.bashrc
  sudo sed -i "5i PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/samba/sbin" /root/.bashrc
  mainmenu
  }

# This installs all of the necessary components for building samba then downloads samba from git.
# After that it then compiles and installs samba and returns to the main menu.

installvsftpd () {
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
  sudo apt-get -y install vsftpd
  mainmenu
  }

# This installs VSFTPd and return to the main menu.


installwebmin () {
  wget http://www.webmin.com/download/deb/webmin-current.deb
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
  sudo dpkg -i webmin-current.deb
  sudo apt-get -y install -f
  rm webmin-current.deb
  mainmenu
  }

# This installs the current version of WebMin and then returns to the main menu.

updatesystem () {
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
  echo "Update Complete!"
  echo "It may be wise to restart your computer..."
  read -n 1
  clear
  mainmenu
  }

# This install the latest updates for the system and then returns to the main menu.


configuresambaforactivedirectory () {
  sudo sed -i.original -r '/[ \t]\/[ \t]/{s/(ext4[\t ]*)([^\t ]*)/\1\2,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1/}' /etc/fstab
  mount -a
  sudo /usr/local/samba/bin/samba-tool domain provision
  sudo mv /etc/krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf.bak
  sudo cp /usr/local/samba/private/krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf
  sudo sed -i "13i sudo /usr/local/samba/sbin/samba" /etc/rc.local
  sudo /usr/local/samba/sbin/samba
  domaincontrolleryorn
  }

# This function runs all of the necessary actions to make samba a domain controller.


domaincontrolleryorn () {
  echo "did you set this instalation as a primary domain controller?"
  echo ""
  echo "If you select yes then it will upgrade the forrest and domain to"
  echo "Server 2008 R2 levels. This may break compatibility with earlier"
  echo "versions of Windows Server. You can alwayse manually change the levels"
  echo "if you wish... Press wisely!"
  echo ""
  echo "Y or N:"
  read -n 1 -p "Y or N:" "omaincontrolleryesorno"
  if [ $domaincontrolleryesorno = "Y" ]; then
   upgradeforrestanddomain
   elif [ "$$domaincontrolleryesorno" = "N" ]; then
            clear
            echo "Samba configuration complete!"
            echo "Press any key to continue..."
            read -n 1
            mainmenu
    elif [ "$$domaincontrolleryesorno" = "n" ]; then
            clear
            echo "Samba configuration complete!"
            echo "Press any key to continue..."
            read -n 1
            mainmenu
    elif [ "$$domaincontrolleryesorno" = "y" ]; then
            upgradeforrestanddomain
    else
      echo "Please press either Y or N!!!"
      echo ""
      echo "Press any key to continue..."
      read -n 1
      clear
      domaincontrolleryorn
    fi
  }

# This asks the user if he or she would like to upgrade the domain and forrest level.
# If yes then it roputs the user to the code below. If not then the user is taken to the main menu.

upgradeforrestanddomain () {
  sudo /usr/local/samba/bin/samba-tool domain level raise --domain-level=2008_R2
  sudo /usr/local/samba/bin/samba-tool domain level raise --forest-level=2008_R2
  sudo /usr/local/samba/bin/samba-tool domain passwordsettings set --complexity=off
  echo "Domain Controller setup has completed!"
  echo ""
  echo "Press any key to return to the main menu..."
  read -n 1
  clear
  mainmenu
  }


# This function upgrade the Domain and Forrest level to (Server) 2008_R2.
# Acceptable levels are 2008 and 2008 R2. The default is 2003.


quitprogram () {
  clear
  echo "Sorry to see you go... :("
  exit
  }

# This is a simple good by program closer.
# Oh, did I mention that it stops the program?


mainmenu () {
  echo "Press 1 to update your system"
  echo "Press 2 to install samba"
  echo "Press 3 to install vsFTPd"
  echo "Press 4 to install the current version of Webmin"
  echo "Press 5 to configure samba for Active Directory"
  echo "Press x to exit the script"
  read -n 1 -p "Input Selection:" "mainmenuinput"
  if [ "$mainmenuinput" = "1" ]; then
            clear
            updatesystem
        elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "2" ]; then
            clear
            installsamba
        elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "3" ]; then
            clear
            installvsftpd
        elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "4" ]; then
            clear
            installwebmin
        elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "5" ]; then
            clear
            configuresambaforactivedirectory
        elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "x" ];then
            clear
            quitprogram
        elif [ "$mainmenuinput" = "X" ];then
            clear
            quitprogram
        else
            echo "You have entered an invallid selection!"
            echo "Please try again!"
            echo ""
            echo "Press any key to continue..."
            read -n 1
            clear
            mainmenu
        fi
}

# This builds the main menu and routs the user to the function selected.

mainmenu

# This executes the main menu function.
# Let the fun begin!!!! WOOT WOOT!!!!
```

You can find this script on github: https://github.com/elliot-labs/Ubuntu-Server-Setup-Automation.
I will update it in the future to add more features.